# understanding tag and article count and query

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

Actually i am trying to understand how to query and count tag and post, just like wordpress and stackexchange does!

**table post**

`id|name|tags`

`1 |a post | 1,2,3`

`2| b post | 2,1`

`3| c post | 3,2`

**table tag**

`id|tags|post_id`

`1|tag1|1,2`

`2|tag2|1,2,3`

`3|tag3|1,3`

**Query to Get tags under post 2 and count**

```
SELECT * 
FROM post
JOIN tag ON (post.id=tag.post_id)
WHERE post.id=2
```

**Query to Get posts under tag2 and count**

```
SELECT *
FROM tag
JOIN post
ON (tag.id=post.tags)
WHERE tag.id=2
```

Comment: And what you trying to do?

Comment: trying to count & get all tags under single post and count all articles under single tag. just like wordpress and stackoverflow does

Comment: If you're trying to do this with SQL as your SELECT statements suggest, your relationship between tags and posts would probably be better modelled as a many-to-many relationship, where you have a tag table, a post table and a post_tag table that describes the links between the two.  Then you can use a query against that middle table, grouped by either tag Id or post Id and counting the other relationships. e.g. SELECT postid, COUNT(1) FROM post_tag GROUP BY postid to get count of tags for each post.